# Xmlparsing with Dynamic content using DOM

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing, sax

I want to parse the xml file with dynamic content using DOM parser in java. I get only for static content. If anyone knows please share the link

Thanks
Bathakarai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JDOM or DOM4J to parse the XML file. Here are the link->

http://www.jdom.org/

http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/